# Plesk deleting IIS log files?

Tags: iis, plesk

So I got this Windows 2003 dedicated virtual server from GoDaddy for a client's sites.  I'm troubleshooting a problem that requires looking at IIS log files going back two weeks.  Unfortunately, when I looked into c:\windows\system32\logfiles\W3SVC[site #], I only found log files for the past five days.  When I checked the following day, the oldest file was gone, so something is keeping that folder trimmed to 5 days of files.  It's not an IIS option as far as I can find.  The only difference between this and another GoDaddy virtual server is that this one has Plesk on it.  Is it possible that Plesk is sucking in these log files for its own stats and either getting rid of them or storing them elsewhere?  GoDaddy was of zero help on this issue.  Thanks for any info..

Comment: You *might* get more traction on this over at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it applies to the ISS version of Plesk (I've only used it with Apache on Linux), but in the 8.x series (it may be different on 9.x) you can change the settings for log file rotation, etc. via the Log Manager -> Log rotation option at the domain level.

Alternatively you can change the master settings for newly created domains via the domain template at the client level.